pip can't install anything in Windows Python Docker container
I have an official Docker container on my hands, it has access to a directory on my PC and is supposed to operate using data from there. The program requires a lot of dependencies, so as a test I try to upgrade pip.
I ping 8.8.8.8. Success:
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=59
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=59
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=59
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=59

I ping Wikipedia. Failure:
ping wikipedia.com
Ping request could not find host wikipedia.com. Please check the name and try again.

I then try to run the command itself to see just what exactly is happening.
Here is the result:
(.venv) C:\.venv\Scripts>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\.venv\lib\site-packages (23.0.1)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewC
onnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AD8D752190>: Failed to establish a new
 connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewC
onnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AD8D7524C0>: Failed to establish a new
 connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewC
onnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AD8D752670>: Failed to establish a new
 connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewC
onnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AD8D752820>: Failed to establish a new
 connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewC
onnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AD8D7529D0>: Failed to establish a new
 connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pip/

I do have Docker Desktop, so maybe there are some settings I can change to make it work. Please help figuring this out, as Internet access is crucial to the program.

That seems like your DNS setup is broken in some way; that's not really a programming-related question.  Given how you've described the problem, it may be easier to run the program out of a non-container Python virtual environment directly on the host system, which will avoid several complexities around both networking and file sharing.

@DavidMaze while it is possible, it opens up many browser windows, interrupting my work every second (literally). We seek a container solution to do this without popup windows, so that is, sadly, out of the question. What could be the problem with the DNS setup?
